# Как разместить текст внизу блока (bootstrap 4.3)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть вот такой блок:

```html
<div class="card mb-1 mt-2">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                колонка слева<br>
                текст<br>
                текст<br>
                текст<br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p class="card-text">Основной текст (много текста)</p>
                <div class="align-bottom">
                    <p class="card-text">Вчера, 19:15 / #2 Удалить Редактировать Ответить</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я добавил для нужного параграфа `align-bottom`, но получается не так как нужно (см. ниже)
[image: скрин]

Comment: Для `div.col-md-10` добавьте три класса: `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between` - https://jsfiddle.net/e0fu7kd4/

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Ты лучший!))))